# How to send commands to elm 327 bluetooth dongle and get results on windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, elm327

I can connect to the elm327 dongle, but when i send it a command i get no response. 
I used the class BluetoothConnectionManager.cs, that can be found here: 
[This lib](https://github.com/jdruid/ArduinoBluetoothLibrary-/blob/master/ArduinoBluetoothLibrary/Connection/BluetoothConnectionManager.cs)

and i used this code to send commands when it got connected:

```
      var cmd = "AT I";
      var res = await this.btManager.SendMessageAsync(cmd);
```

this is the Capabilities part of Package.appxmanifest:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```